# RewriteRule slash optional

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

When I put "?" after slash to make it optional, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/?$     "/index.php?page=view-user&user=$1"
```

But now when I open URL with slash like /user/revolution/ in PHP, $_GET['user'] output "rloveution/" (with slash).
So how can I make the trailing slash optional without getting username output with slash ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negated regex:

```
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=view-user&user=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Or lazy matching:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.+?)/?$ index.php?page=view-user&user=$1 [L,QSA]
```